# Script how to remove extension and put in separate column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to take the column filename and just create a new column called extension after the ‘.’  This needs to be a View called extensions.

This script works in **ACCESS**, but there seems to be no equivalent to -`InStrRev`.

```
SELECT [UserProfile12_7-512-1mb].FileName,
       Right([Filename], Len([Filename])-InStrRev([Filename],".")) AS Extension,
       [UserProfile12_7-512-1mb].ComputerName,
       [UserProfile12_7-512-1mb].KB
FROM [UserProfile12_7-512-1mb];
```

Then I need to create another script using the New View extensions and join another table and group by the last extension.
In ACCESS the script is this:

```
SELECT ExtensionSheet.Extension, Sum([UserProfile12_7-512-1mb].KB) AS SumOfKB
FROM [UserProfile12_7-512-1mb]
INNER JOIN ExtensionSheet ON [UserProfile12_7-512-1mb].ComputerName = ExtensionSheet.ComputerName
GROUP BY ExtensionSheet.Extension;
```

Here are screen shots of the tables:

[image: Table2]
[image: Table1]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression.

```
RIGHT(t.[FileName],IIF(CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(t.[FileName]))>0,CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(t.[FileName]))-1,0 ))
```

The whole query can be

```
SELECT t.FileName, 
    RIGHT(t.[FileName],IIF(CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(t.[FileName]))>0,CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(t.[FileName]))-1,0 )) AS Extension,
    t.ComputerName,
    t.KB 
FROM [UserProfile12_7-512-1mb] t;
```

I do not know how you create your view, but this will give you the results.

```
WITH ExtensionSheet AS (
    SELECT t.FileName, 
        RIGHT(t.[FileName],IIF(CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(t.[FileName]))>0,CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(t.[FileName]))-1,0 )) AS Extension
        t.ComputerName,
        t.KB 
    FROM [UserProfile12_7-512-1mb] t
)
SELECT
    e.Extension
    , SUM(t1.KB) AS SUMOfKB
FROM
    ExtensionSheet e
    JOIN [UserProfile12_7-512-1mb] t1 ON e.Extension=RIGHT(t1.[FileName],IIF(CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(t1.[FileName]))>0,CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(t1.[FileName]))-1,0 ))
GROUP BY
    e.Extension;
```

Or this (if you created the view already).

```
SELECT
    e.Extension
    , SUM(t1.KB) AS SUMOfKB
FROM
    ExtensionSheet e
    JOIN [UserProfile12_7-512-1mb] t1 ON e.Extension=RIGHT(t1.[FileName],IIF(CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(t1.[FileName]))>0,CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(t1.[FileName]))-1,0 ))
GROUP BY
    e.Extension;
```

Comment: Ok, that works great, no how do I do the second query, with the join?

Comment: I reveived
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.